# C++ std::stringstream >> std::string only stores first entry?

Tags: c++, stringstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force std::stringstream operator >> to read an entire string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136359/how-to-force-stdstringstream-operator-to-read-an-entire-string)

I am trying to convert a structure to a string, similar to how toString() would work for an object in Java or C++. To do this I am writing my formatted data to a std::stringstream then write that to a std::string.

Here is what I have:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string       packet;

ss <<  "Packet Length: " << p->header->len
   << " (" << p->header->caplen << ")" << std::endl
   << "Collected: " <<  timedate << "."
   << std::dec << p->header->ts_usecs << std::endl
   << "Eth:\tFrom: " << to_address(p->from) << std::endl
   <<     "\tTo:   " << to_address(p->to)  << std::endl
   <<     "\tType: " << to_hex(p->type, false)
   << " (" << p->type_name << ")" << std::endl;
```

But for some reason when I write this stream into the std::string packet:

```
ss >> packet;
```

and then print the value of packet:

```
cout << "Packet X " << packet << endl;
```

I only see the text `"Packet"` and nothing else.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: @BoPersson My question is more about why I am not getting the full string. If I knew `>>` didn't read the full string I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of reading a string back, you should get the value using the [`stringstream ::str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/) member:

```
string p = ss.str();
```

Otherwise, the reading follows the usual pattern of treating spaces as separators.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple like this. I had been using the `>>` operator to load all of my other data into strings, I guess they just happened to not have spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the `std::string` out of a `stringstream`, you do this:

```
packet = ss.str();
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple like this. I had been using the `>>` operator to load all of my other data into strings, I guess they just happened to not have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

StringStream operator >> works like any other stream operator >>.
So for parameter string (>> to string) it will give data to first white char (space, new line, end of file, etc.)